# Creating new Orchard Core CMS 1.6.0 Theme

Tags: orchardcms-1.6

I have an existing web site that I wish to convert to the latest (1.6.0) Orchard Core. I had previously attempted to do this with an earlier version of Orchard Core with some success but then got busy with work and had to set it aside. Now, after leaving my last job -- they offered me a very nice severance -- I decided to take some time off and get this web site up and running.

Unfortunately for me, things seem to have changed in how Orchard sets up themes then to now. Whereas all themes sat in a shared "Theme" directory, they are now individual projects. Making this even more challenging, I can find no sample projects to work with. I've certainly found no examples regarding the default themes. I tried copying the Layout.cshtml from my original attempt but it won't compile. Instead, it gives me errors like "HasText/SetMeta/Style does not exist in current context". I found a MaterialDesignTheme that is a project, but when I attempt it's Layout.cshtml, I get a similar message but for things like "Orchard/RenderTitleSegments/Site".

Can someone show me where to look or what I'm missing so that I can get this going? I've searched all over the All-Knowing 'Net for some kind of answer to this. Maybe I've missed it, but I can find nothing that provides me much on how to create a theme for version 1.6.0 of Orchard. Not on the Orchard site, not even on the Lombiq site. Clues appreciated.

Comment: Well, I managed to solve one of my problems by locating the latest 1.6.0 project. It had all the available themes that come with an Orchard installation. Duplicating the Agency theme, I was able to create a new one but that wasn't exactly an easy process either. I was able to solve some of my previous issues, but I now have a completely new set of "challenges". :/